# Remove unused methods/classes from dependencies

Tags: java, maven

Many libraries contain much more functions than I need. If I shade them into my jar, the jar contains 80% code which is never used.

Is there a way to remove any unused methods & classes from the dependencies I shade into my jar?

Comment: Proguard can remove unnecessary code from a Jar.

Comment: Do you have appropriate unit/integration tests which shows that all your code is working correctly with the reduced jar's?

Comment: I don't think there's much sense in doing this. Less memory used? I doubt that it's worth it

Comment: The maven-shade-plugin has the `minimizeJar` option. Be aware of all the warnings mentioned by others. In general none of these solutions can detect reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have extremely good integration tests I advise to be really careful about this idea.

Far too often frameworks might use reflection here or there - and no tool can determine through static analysis which parts of the code will be called via reflection.

Beyond that: how many megabytes are we talking here? Keep in mind that a Java SE installation contains many thousand classes which you will never be using.

What I mean: is this a *real* problem or a *assumed* one? Did a customer complain about too many dependencies? Is there anything that causes *real* trouble for you? Then, and only then you should be looking into reducing the "jar content".

Finally: keep in mind that *you* are the one who created those dependencies in the first place! So, when you are worried about the number of items pulled in for your product - maybe you first check if there are ways to reduce the direct dependencies of your product. Instead of going with a "too large" list and that idea to reduce jar contents as suggested in the question.